# Как в одном AJAX запросе обработать несколько echo?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Допустим есть вот такой `ajax` запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    success: function (response) {
    //какое-то действие здесь
    };
});
```

И `action.php`:

```
   <?php 
    while(true){
    //выполняется какая-то логика
    echo json_encode(//какие-то данные);
    }
   ?>
```

Возможно ли после каждого `echo` обрабатывать в `ajax` запросе эти данные и ждать пока придет следущая порция данных?

Comment: Видится long polling, либо  setInterval пока не придет признак последней "порции", либо... $data = ... while(true){$data+=....} json_encode($data);

Comment: @sepggm, Всю инфу одним json файлом не вариант отправлять.

Comment: Я собирал данные таким образом от сервака и, когда они приходили, добавлял автоматически в DOM на клиенте. Может, подойдет такой же вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте так называемый `comet`:

На стороне сервера:

```
for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    sleep(1);

    $arr = array("time" => time());

    echo "<script>parent.callback(" . json_encode($arr) . ")</script>";

    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

На стороне клиента:

```
<iframe id="comet"></iframe>
<script>
function start() {
    document.getElementById('comet').src = 'comet.php';
}
function stop() {
    document.getElementById('comet').src = '';
}

function callback(data) {
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(data);
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="start()" value="start">
<input type="button" onclick="stop()" value="stop">
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http работает по принципу запрос-ответ, и чтобы вам отправлять сообщения с сервера без запросов с клиента, нужно либо реализовать протокол веб сокетов(возможно и другие есть, не проверял), либо отправлять запрос после каждого ответа(ну, чтобы по частям получать)

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообще, если через ванильный [JS(XHR)](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest), то там есть событие `progress`, у которого в `event` есть свойство `responseText`. Если отсекать эхи по 50мс(`usleep(500000)`), (а именно через такие промежутки браузер проверяет чего там приходит от сервера), но, это справедливо для латиницы в ASCII, т.к. в UTF-8, каждый символ хранится в 2х байтах, и при таких попытках прочитать промежуточное состояние, можно получить некорректное отображение. Решение костыльное, неоправданно накрученное, и в целом неусместное, но, раз уж надо:

`echo 'foobar'; usleep(500000)`

`xhr.onprogress = function(event){ console.log(event.responseText); }`

---

Если задача отслеживать прогресс какого-то очень емкого процесса на сервере, то по моему самым правильным будет генерить айдишник процесса, скинуть его клиенту,  икидать его в базу, и апдейтить там прогресс. А ajax'ом, через сторонний php файл чекать по айдишнику прогресс. Если схематично, то выйдет как то так:

**ajax** =(event)=> **php(process)** =(uid)=> **ajax** =(uid)=> **php(progress_observer)** =(percentage)=> **ajax** =(uid)=> **php(progress_observer)** =(percentage_100)=> **ajax**